# Can't get data between two dates with different year SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have this query to get the data between two dates. It's working fine for dates in the year 2020 but it's not working when I used dates from year 2019.

Example:

```
SELECT * FROM TASKS_TBL WHERE GROUP_NAME = 'Group Name Sample' 
AND SUB_PROJECT_IDX = 'subproject_test' 
AND START_DATE BETWEEN '01/01/2020'
AND AND DATE('now') 
AND DUE_DATE <='05/18/2020';
```

The above query retrieves all data between the given dates

Not Working Example:

```
SELECT * FROM TASKS_TBL WHERE GROUP_NAME = 'Group Name Sample' 
AND SUB_PROJECT_IDX = 'subproject_test' 
AND START_DATE BETWEEN '01/01/2019'
AND AND DATE('now') 
AND DUE_DATE <='05/18/2020';
```

When I'm using dates from 2019 It's not retrieving the data from 2019 - 2020 instead of its retrieving the data's from 01/01/2020 up to 05/18/2020

I've already double-checked the data in the database I have data ranging from 2019 to 2020 and it has the same Group Name and Sub Project IDX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the format of your dates to 'YYYY-MM-DD' which is the only valid and comparable format in SQLite:

```
UPDATE TASKS_TBL  
SET START_DATE = SUBSTR(START_DATE, 7) || '-' || SUBSTR(START_DATE, 1, 2) || '-' || SUBSTR(START_DATE, 4, 2),
    DUE_DATE = SUBSTR(DUE_DATE, 7) || '-' || SUBSTR(DUE_DATE, 1, 2) || '-' || SUBSTR(DUE_DATE, 4, 2)
```

and your code to:

```
BETWEEN '2019-01-01' AND AND DATE('now') 
AND DUE_DATE <='2020-05-18'
```

and the query will work fine.

Answer (score 1):

Use standard date formats!

```
SELECT *
FROM TASKS_TBL
WHERE GROUP_NAME = 'Group Name Sample'  AND
      SUB_PROJECT_IDX = 'subproject_test' AND
      START_DATE >= '2019-01-01' AND
      DUE_DATE <= '2020-05-18';
```

Adjust the dates as appropriate.